# Codeigniter Cookie Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

Cookies arent being set in my first view.

Is this how it should be ? or am I mistaken

Please view the code below for further illustration:

```
 if( !get_cookie('rate') ){



            $cookie_rate = array(
                   'name'   => 'rate',
                   'value'  => '10',
                   'expire' => '100000'
             );

             set_cookie($cookie_rate);
     }
   var_dump( get_cookie('rate') ); //returns ( boolean false )

   if( !isset($_COOKIE['foo']) ){
            $_COOKIE['foo'] = 'bar';
   }

   var_dump( $_COOKIE['foo'] ); // This yields string 'bar' (length=3) on the first visit
```

Doing the same thing with php cookies yeilds an array with cookie values.

- This problem persists only in the first visit of a page.

Comment: `$_COOKIE['foo'] = 'bar'` **does not set the cookie on the browser!!!**  All it does is add `foo` to the `$_COOKIE` array. `foo` will not be on `$_COOKIE` on the next request.  The equivalent to CodeIgniter `set_cookie()` is PHP `setcookie()`, which you will see does *not* alter `$_COOKIE` on the current request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a CodeIgniter vs PHP issue. You just don't understand how cookies work.

Cookies are a header sent by the server which the browser must send back on subsequent requests. `$this->input->set_cookie()` and `set_cookie()` *send* a cookie header.

`$_COOKIES` on PHP (and thus `$this->input->cookie()` and therefore the `get_cookie()` helper) only contain cookies which the *browser* sent.

Thus when you set a cookie with `set_cookie()`, you won't be able to `get_cookie()` until the browser's next request.

Comment: Mmmmyeaah, but the *expected* behaviour could easily be emulated by a framework like CI by also storing newly set values in an internal lookup array. To be honest, I'm surprised it's not doing that.

Comment: CodeIgniter is not that clever.  It doesn't buffer cookie-sets until the end of the request, for example, so if you call `set_cookie()` twice with the same data, you'll get two headers sent from the server. Plus, the OP was expecting the data to be in `$_COOKIE`, so it's not as if he thought this is something CI would do for him--he really didn't understand cookies even in pure PHP.

Comment: Please view my edit with Native PHP. I do know how cookies work but seems odd that setting cookies in PHP the first time does dump a value while codeigniter does not.

Comment: Please view my comment to your edit. Assigning to `$_COOKIE` does *not* send cookies.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as CI's `set_cookie` probably utilizes the same mechanism as PHP's `setcookie()`, this entry from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) probably applies:

> **Common pitfalls**
>
> Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie expires. Expire time is set via the expire parameter. A nice way to debug the existence of cookies is by simply calling print_r($_COOKIE);.

I can't see any mention of this behaviour in the [CI manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html), but it's likely to be the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood this right youre trying to see the data of the cookie before reloading the page which won't work. Try setting the cookie, reloading the page and then checking the cookie for data.

Also sometimes you need to specify domain and such, perhaps it doesn't apply right now but it might be nice to know later if they suddenly stop working, from CI-documentation:

```
$cookie = array(
'name'   => 'The Cookie Name',
'value'  => 'The Value',
'expire' => '86500',
'domain' => '.some-domain.com',
'path'   => '/',
'prefix' => 'myprefix_',
'secure' => TRUE
);

$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

Also, consider using the session class instead of cookies if you don't need anything specifically from cookies since they are more secure. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 1):

Thats probably not the problem, in fact thats how cookie works, its set and on next page load it seems to be visible from then.